# Are there any Bluetooth LE light dimmers with open APIs?

Tags: smart-home, bluetooth-low-energy, lighting

Are there any smart light switches/dimmers that support [Bluetooth Low Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy) and have an open or accessible APIs?

I want to gradually replace all *dumb switches* in my house with *smart switches*, but don't want to deal with any proprietary apps. Are there any such switches?

Comment: The Nuimo from Senic may be interesting, though I will/may be way too expensive. Why do you specifically want BLE?

Comment: check out Xicato controls. Their AI is very good. https://www.xicato.com/products/controls/

Answer (score 13):

In general Bluetooth equipment always comes with a proprietary app for your phone...

I think that if you want to have the control over your Bluetooth switches, you might want to take a look at [Arduino Bluetooth modules](https://diyhacking.com/arduino-bluetooth-basics/) and command relays on it to toggle normal lamps.

Comment: I'm fine if it comes with proprietary app as long as I can't replicate communication protocol and replace it with my own software. I know that there are documents for RF protocols of Oregon Scientific thermometers and such.

I can put together arduino and relays, it's just that it would be very hard for me to create something that is mechanically reliable, electrically safe, aesthetically pleasing and would fit in place of a wall switch within reasonable time and money constraints.

I'd rather get finished device and focus on the software

Comment: Note that Bluetooth is not the same as BTLE which is more commonly used for this.  Each tends to have its own issues.

Answer (score 7):

The closest to an answer that I can come to is this list of products supported by [openhab](http://www.openhab.org/features/supported-technologies.html). It doesn't identify which products use Bluetooth LE, but does identify products (indirectly) where the protocol is known.